# Angular two the same controllers in single view

Tags: angularjs

Wondering how to use 2 the same controllers in a single view in Angular, I separated my controllers in different files to make a clean ctrl structure, but wondering if you're allowed to do something like this?

Basically I want to update the table view after uploading a file, its somewhat working but I have to refresh the whole page for the view to refresh.

```
<div class="view">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
    controller the table
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="otherCtrl as vm"> </div>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
    <button ng-click="clickbtn()"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code is in myCtrl controller.

```
$scope.$on("$UploadFile", function (event) {
    // do the action here digestion
});

$scope.uploadCv = function(event) {
  $scope.$broadcast("$UploadFile"); 
}
```

Comment: well have you tried it???

Comment: You might need to use $rootScope.$broadcast rather than $scope.$broadcast

Comment: Well I think I did mention it that it kind of work but it seems to be getting confuse or something :/

Comment: @Rob Ah I will try that.

Comment: Something similar to this? https://jsfiddle.net/gzgkz3cr/

Comment: Well, looks like you have several problems actually. 1: You're not passing the data as a second parameter in the $broadcast function.  2: You're not asking for the data in the $on function. Take a look at the fiddle I sent.

Comment: @Rob not quite as those are two different controllers just assigned the same. What I meant is to have both "myController as vm" on each div. I used $scope.$broadcast because its all in one controller just separated by html structure due to other controllers in the html.

Comment: @Rob Marking your jsFiddle :) because it seems to be similar in some ways.